# monitor html change using hash func

Tags: c#, hash, html-agility-pack

I want to write an application that gets a list of urls.

For each of them I need to monitor periodically if the content has changed.

I thought :

1. to use HtmlAgilityPack to fetch html content (any other recommendation?)
2. I don't need to spot the change itself,

so I though to hash the content, save it in the DB

and re-compare the has in the future.

How would you suggest hashing?  .net's GetHashCode() ?

I saw this documentation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020

which advise using

```
tmpSource = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sSourceData);
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *absolutely not* use `GetHashCode()` for this. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) explicitly states:

> Furthermore, the .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same between different versions of the .NET Framework.

The results of `GetHashCode` can change between runs - all that's guaranteed is that calling it on two equal objects *in the same process* (possibly AppDomain) will give the same hash code. Indeed, `String.GetHashCode`'s algorithm *has* changed over time, and in .NET 4 the 32-bit implementation is different to the 64-bit implementation.

If you want to use hashing, use MD5, SHA1 etc - something with a specified algorithm which *will not change*. (Note that these operation on binary data rather than string data, which is probably more appropriate too - you don't need to bother decoding the data as text.)

It's not clear to me whether refetching periodically is *really* the best idea though - do these servers not support last modified times, [etags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) etc?

Comment: "do these servers..." the ones that host the web-pages? I cannot count on it, but I can make it as flow in my checking

Comment: @EladBenda: Right - if you can use that to avoid repeatedly downloading, it would help a lot.

Comment: Who is in charge to update the eTags? The site owner? Or is it done transparently?

Comment: @EladBenda: I don't know much about etags (follow the link) but I believe it's transparent.

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked for suggestions. I would have used this method instead

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
```

And i would have saved this string in my DB. After the particular interval i could have compared them again.

But yes I do agree the string size would be really be large.
If I just want to get a alert on the fact the content has changed some how. I would use MD5. As the result size of an MD5 string is only 27 characters.

Hence easier to compare and store in DB

Comment: encryption using MD5 - actually includes hashing? meaning it keeps one-to-one uniqueness?

Comment: MD5 is hashing, *not* encryption. And no, it's not 1:1, because that's not what hashing is meant for. It's meant to be a good *indication* of uniqueness, not a guarantee.

Comment: I do agree with you. But either of the case you can easily compare the changes once the value change.